# How to send Google Form results to a particular sheet ("tab") of a Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-forms

Is there a way to create a Form that submits to a particular TAB of a Google Sheet?

Use Case:

We are using this for meeting pre-check-in. There's standard form. I'd like the results for each participant to go to their own TAB.

Answer (score 0):

## Short answer

Use [Google Apps Script](http://www.google.com/script/start)

## Explanation

This isn't built-in function on Google Forms or Google Sheets, but we could create bounded script projects on forms and spreadsheets. Both have an onFormSubmit installable trigger that could be used to send the form submissions as soon as their occur to the desired tab.

Another alternative is to create a script to be triggered by other means, like from the Apps Script editor, just to mention one.

A third alternative could be to use an add-on, if there is already one that do this.